# Is this a BUG in Laragon / Laravel 8? - 2 or more projects trying to look for tables in each others database

Tags: mysql, laravel-8, laragon

I have 2 Laravel projects running on my Laragon setup. Individually they appear to work fine but if I am loading both in different Chrome windows then they will start to connect to the same database.

Lets call the 1st one Crawler and the 2nd Hub.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blackcrawler
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=core
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Both setups are using the standard Database configuration, Crawler connects to the `blackcrawler` database and the Hub connects to `core`.

Crawler is a crawling process analysing pages for a website I point it too.
As that loops if I visit a page on the HUB the next time the crawler process loads it tries to connect to the `core`.`pages` table. After a couple of F5/refresh of the browser it will go back to connecting to the correct database.

Equally if I then try to login to the hub it will try to connect to the `blackcrawler`.`users` table.

I am running:
Laragon Full 4.0.16 with PHP 7.4.28.

Hub is running: Laravel Framework 8.77.1

Crawler is running: Laravel Framework 8.83.5

At no point am I running any commands in the terminal for it to switch databases. Only refreshing the browsers. The projects are in completely independant folders.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour is it possibly something to do with NPM? Both are running 8.1.2

Just to elaborate - this isn't limited to just these projects I have quite a few and in testing with another 2-3 the same thing happens. Interestingly I have non-laravel projects and if I load one of those it doesn't have the same impact on a Laravel project.

Any help on fixing my issue would be appreciated as I quite often are working on 2-3 projects at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug of Laragon. If you google, you'll find some similar issues with Laravel:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19820

I also find that the issues only happen with Apache.
My suggestion is using Nginx instead.

Comment: Thank you Leoo - you see I was thinking it was a database issue - I was being too specific. I didn't consider it to be related to the .env in general.